# Create a new list according to item value

Tags: python, list

I have a list like below.

```
  ['T46', 'T43', 'R45', 'R44', 'B46', 'B43', 'L45', 'L44', 'C46', 'C45']
```

where I want to group according to int value:

```
  [id][' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']   # AREA PATTERN [Top, Right, Bottom, Left, Center]

  [46]['1','0','1','0','1']   #Top,Bottom,Center
  [45]['0','1','0','1','1']   #Right,Left,Center
  [43]['1','0','1','0','0']   #Top,Bottom
  [44]['0','1','0','1','0']   #Right,Left
```

Is this possible? What I tried so far is:

```
  id_area = []
  for a in area:
      id = a[1:3]
      areas = a[:1]
      if any(str(id) in s for s in area):
                id_area = #lost
```

Comment: How do the items in that list correlate to your group example?

Comment: Oh.. so the two numbered digit is the group and then the first character is flags... gotcha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating a `dict` and then map the values based on the integer value

```
from collections import defaultdict

mapping = defaultdict(list)
items = ['T46', 'T43', 'R45', 'R44', 'B46', 'B43', 'L45', 'L44', 'C46', 'C45']

for i in items:
    mapping[int(i[1:])].append(i[0])

print(mapping)
>>> defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {43: ['T', 'B'], 44: ['R', 'L'], 45: ['R', 'L', 'C'], 46: ['T', 'B', 'C']})
```

From there, you can create a `list` with the `areas` and then reassign the values in your `dict` the area pattern

```
areas = ['T', 'L', 'B', 'R', 'C']    
area_pattern = {k: [1 if l in v else 0 for l in areas] for k, v in mapping.items()}

for key, areas in area_pattern.items():
    print(key, areas)

>>> 43 [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
>>> 44 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
>>> 45 [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
>>> 46 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: how can I get `areas[0]`? in  `[(key, areas) for key, areas in area_pattern.items()]`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for?

```
In [1]: lst =  ['T46','T43','R45','R44','B46','B43','L45','L44', 'C46', 'C45']

In [2]: [1 if x.endswith("46") else 0 for x in lst]
Out[2]: [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

In [3]: [1 if x.endswith("43") else 0 for x in lst]
Out[3]: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: I'll start from your idea, is it possible to achieve the pattern `AREA PATTERN [Top, Right, Bottom, Left, Center]`

Answer (score 0):

With `itertools.groupby()` function:

```
import itertools

l = ['T46', 'T43', 'R45', 'R44', 'B46', 'B43', 'L45', 'L44', 'C46', 'C45']
coords_str = 'TRBLC'    # Top, Right, Bottom, Left, Center
result = {}

for k,g in itertools.groupby(sorted(l, key=lambda x:x[1:]), key=lambda x:x[1:]):
    items = list(_[0] for _ in g)
    result[k] = [int(c in items) for c in coords_str]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
{'44': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], '45': [0, 1, 0, 1, 1], '43': [1, 0, 1, 0, 0], '46': [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy to read.

```
>>> letters = {'T': 0, 'R': 1, 'B': 2, 'L': 3, 'C': 4}
>>> carlos_list =  ['T46', 'T43', 'R45', 'R44', 'B46', 'B43', 'L45', 'L44', 'C46', 'C45']
>>> result = {_:5*['0'] for _ in range(43,47)}
>>> for item in carlos_list:
...     list_location = letters[item[0]]
...     slot = int(item[1:])
...     result[slot][list_location] = '1'
... 
>>> result
{43: ['1', '0', '1', '0', '0'], 44: ['0', '1', '0', '1', '0'], 45: ['0', '1', '0', '1', '1'], 46: ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1']}
```